# IIS7 Win 2008 + ASP MVC http result 504 status with static files css, js, images

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Randomly accessing static files on our web site returns http 504 error status code

From fiddler:

> Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching
>   Content-Type Process Comments Custom
>   288 504 HTTP
>   /assets/styles/site1.css 512 text/html
>   ekrn:700 289 504 HTTP
>   /assets/styles/rightmenu.css 512
>   text/html ekrn:700 291 504 HTTP
>   /assets/scripts/jquery.cookie.js 512
>   text/html ekrn:700

Fiddler gives information

> HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
>   Content-Type: text/html Connection:
>   close Timestamp: 08:30:45:8693
>
> ReadResponse() failed: The server did
>   not return a response for this
>   request.

The 504 error still appears. This website runs on the same port and ip with over website (multibinding iis function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was disabling on router HTTP Multiplexing feature.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well.  Disabling Compression on dynamic and static resources resolved it for me.  Still searching for the reasons why and if there's a resolution (software update?) so that I can re-enable compression.  I'll check the router thing...

Answer (score 1):

504 is not a valid IIS Status Code. Check the IIS logfile and see what is the status code for the static files. Please explain further what is the error message and what are you using Fiddler for.

Comment: iis log gives only 304 and 200 status

Comment: so according to IIS the Request / Response is perfectly normal. Now, towards your main issue. What is your issue? I see ReadResponse() failed.. when did that happen. If you want we can take this offline.

Comment: fiddler (sometimes) gives 504 for these resources so page is not properly displayed (styles are not apply etc). I read that 504 is error related with network.

Comment: You can also enable FREB n check for the static files having the problem

Comment: I check FREB and iis logs. There is nothing related with 504 code problem.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question.. but what is this "ekrn" at the end of every response? Is this your AntiVirus? Pls exclude your AV from scanning the content folder and see if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Fiddler traces, all failing requests are returned as text/html. You might want to look at the actual response content to see if there's some more details.

Also, look at the IIS logs to see what exactly IIS got as a request and what it did respond with.